# Printing Odd and Even number using 2 threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized, runnable

I have tried this code. But after printing 0 , it doesn't print anything.
It is blocking due to some lock I think.

```
public class EvenOdd implements Runnable {
    private Object o = new Object();
    private volatile int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println();
            if ( Thread.currentThread().getName().equals( "Even")) {
                printEven();
            } else {
                printOdd();
            }
        } catch ( Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printEven() throws InterruptedException {
        while ( true) {
            synchronized ( o) {
                while ( this.i % 2 == 0) {
                    o.wait();
                }
                System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
                i++;
                o.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    private void printOdd() throws InterruptedException {
        while ( true) {
            synchronized ( o) {
                while ( this.i % 2 != 0) {
                    o.wait();
                }
                System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
                i++;
                o.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My TestClass:

```
EvenOdd x = new EvenOdd();
        new Thread(x,"Even").start();
        new Thread(x,"Odd").start();
```

Where am I wrong?
Thank.

P.S : I know this type of question has been asked many times , but I want to try by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guesses is you are;

- using one Runnable but both of then think they are even i.e. they both see the first value of 0
- printEven has to wait for an odd number ad printOdd has to wait for an even number

EDIT: After running the code the OP fixed the code, it prints

```
0
1
```

as expected. It may sometimes print 0 and 0 randomly as the first check for odd/even is not synchronized.

Comment: I have added test class.

Comment: @Raj So one suggestion applies ;).

Comment: you are saying  in my printEven method . I should change condition to `while(this.i % 2 == 0){`

Comment: @Raj and change printOdd as well.

Comment: After seeing your points on SF , It seems very bad to ask. But can you try this piece of code.

Comment: After changing , it does not work. I also tried by putting Thread t2 for sleep for 2 seconds. Still it is not working.

Comment: @Raj after you fix the first issue. ;) Have you tried using a debugger to debug your program?

Comment: Yes.I tried. Also one interesting thing is when I tried through debug program, instead of printing just 0 . It is printing 0 and then 1 also.

Comment: If it is not working for you you need to ensure the two threads are not both calling printEven().

Comment: I guess both are calling printEven(). How I can ensure one go in even and other go in odd block. Is there is a way other than creating ThreadLocal variable

Comment: @Raj You need synchronized access to a variable which decides one is odd and the other is even. A ThreadLocal variable wouldn't help. Don't need a link as you are going to fix it. ;)

Comment: I did it.It is working fine. I can decide which one is odd or even by giving name to thread. See my updated code in the question. See my run method and test class.

Comment: One last question. I removed volatile field for `i` . Then also I check there is no inconsistency in the o/p. So inside synchronization block all values are read from main memory and not from cache?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple deadlock:

Thread 1 waits for someone to notify on the lock. Thread 2 waits for someone to notify on the same lock.

Since no one ever gets to `o.notify();`, nothing happens.

And `i` is 0 when both threads start, so both first call `printEven()`. Now when that has happened, both threads will then call `printOdd()` in the next round.

Comment: Where I can change to remove the deadlock?

Comment: You are saying both of threads are going in first printEven() loop ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you take a big piece of paper and draw a diagram of the threads. Use tokens or coins to express states (who has the lock, who waits for the lock, what's the value of `i`) and simulate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is when one thread is running, the other has to wait. Once the thread prints the value, it has to wait until the other thread prints. This is achieved by using wait/notify mechanism.

When Odd thread completes printing the value, it notifies the waiting thread(Even thread) and the Even thread becomes ready to run but will wait for the lock to be released by the Odd thread. Now the odd thread calls wait on the locker object so that it releases the lock and goes to wait state. At this point, the only thread waiting for locker object's lock is Even thread and it runs. This process continues alternatively.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object locker = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new OddWorker(locker));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new EvenWorker(locker));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}

class OddWorker implements Runnable {
    private Object locker;
    private int number = 1, count = 1;

    OddWorker(Object locker) {
        this.locker = locker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (locker){
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + number);
                    number += 2;
                    locker.notify();
                    locker.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while(++count < 11);
            locker.notify();
        }
    }
}

class EvenWorker implements Runnable {
    private Object locker;
    private int number = 2, count = 1;

    EvenWorker(Object locker) {
        this.locker = locker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (locker){
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + number);
                    number += 2;
                    locker.notify();
                    locker.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while(++count < 11);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be sure to keep in mind that we expect answers to *specifically* address the question being asked. If there is code in the question, your answer should address that code itself.